# How do I extract the weights used by NIntegrate?

Tags: numerical-integration

I'd like to use `NIntegrate` to adaptively integrate an expression, then use the same points and weights to integrate that expression with some parameters changed. I know I can extract the points used by `NIntegrate` using `EvaluationMonitor`. Is there an analogous way to get the weights?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96663)?

Comment: I hadn't seen that, no. IntegrationMonitor doesn't seem to contain the relevant information, but it might be possible to get it out of the tracing code provided in that answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Matt I thought that the application of `IntegrationMonitor` to this question is not that straightforward so that is why I provided an answer.

Comment: related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54575/2079

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Procedure outline**

The concrete steps depend on which strategy and integration rules are used. Let us assume that:

1. `"GlobalAdaptive"` is used with one of the deterministic rules (e.g. `"GaussKronrodRule"` or `"ClenshawCurtisRule"`),
2. no singularity handling is applied (using the option `"SingularityHandler"->None`).

With these assumptions we can do the re-integration in the following way.

1. Find the last collection of regions used by `"GlobalAdaptive"`. `IntegrationMonitor` can be used to get the iteration step and the integration regions at that step. See the explantions in the second update of my answer to ["Determining which rule NIntegrate selects automatically"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26401/determining-which-rule-nintegrate-selects-automatically/96663#96663).
2. For each region object `robj` change the integrand with the new integrand and apply the integration rule of `robj`.
3. Sum the results of the previous step.

There are some problems applying step 2 directly, so instead we can use the function `IRuleEstimate` defined in `NIntegrate[]`'s advanced documentation (see [NIntegrate Integration Strategies](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html) ).

**Code**

Preliminary definitions:

```
Clear[IRuleEstimate]
IRuleEstimate[f_, {a_, b_}, absc_, weights_, errweights_] := 
  Module[{integral, 
    error}, {integral, 
     error} = (b - a) Total@
      MapThread[{f[#1] #2, f[#1] #3} &, {Rescale[
         absc, {0, 1}, {a, b}], weights, errweights}];
   {integral, Abs[error]}];

nPoints = 5;
{absc, weights, errweights} = 
      NIntegrate`GaussKronrodRuleData[nPoints, MachinePrecision];
```

First integration:

```
F[x_] := 1/Sqrt[Abs[x]]

Block[{k = 0}, {val, {iregions}} = 
   Reap@NIntegrate[F[x], {x, -1, 10}, PrecisionGoal -> 6, 
     Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", 
       Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> nPoints}, 
       "SingularityHandler" -> None}, 
     IntegrationMonitor :> (Sow[{k++, #}] &)]
  ];
```

Re-integration:

```
newF[x_] := 1/Sqrt[1 + x + x^2]

Total@
 Map[IRuleEstimate[newF, #["Boundaries"[]][[1]], absc, weights, 
    errweights] &, iregions[[-1, 2]]]

(* {3.73937, 7.95498*10^-9} *)
```

Check:

```
Integrate[newF[x], {x, -1, 10}]
% // N

(* ArcSinh[1/Sqrt[3]] + ArcSinh[7 Sqrt[3]] *)

(* 3.73937 *)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm assuming the generalization to multiple dimensions is fairly straightforward, depending on how IntegrationMonitor records boundaries? Also, if I wanted to use Singularity Handling (say if I knew that the singularities would be similar in the functions I'm looking at), how would the answer change?

Comment: @Matt For multi-dimensional integrals the function `IRuleEstimate` (i) has to be given abscissas and weights corresponding to the dimension, and (ii) the rescaling has to be done for all axes. As for the singularity handling, I would say it is not that straightforward because of the related variable transformations. (Too lengthy to explain further here.) I would consider posting an update for multi-dimensional integrals...

Comment: @Matt, actually, I would suggest asking the multidimensional case as a separate question instead of as an update to this one; it's sufficiently different and complicated to warrant a separate thread, I reckon.

Comment: Anton: if memory serves, the Iri-Moriguti-Takasawa handler for singularities is already sufficiently complicated... :)

Comment: @J.M. Agreed -- "IMT" is complicated and "DuffyCoordinates" is not that simple either.